# Why FormRecord doesn't allow to use object as a first argument?

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 14 added a new class called FormRecord which allows to create form controls more dynamic than FormGroup.
Docs got an example which goes like this

> FormRecord accepts one generic argument, which describes the type of the controls it contains.

```
let numbers = new FormRecord({bill: '415-123-456'});
numbers.addControl('bob', '415-234-567');
numbers.removeControl('bill');
```

But when I use that example in my code I got an error

```
let numbers = new FormRecord({bill: '415-123-456'}); // TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AbstractControl<never, never>'. 
numbers.addControl('bob', '415-234-567'); // TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl '.
```

When it comes to package.json it looks like this

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    (...)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    (...)
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a documentation error that didn't get caught during the release.

See the [top of the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormRecord):

> `extends FormGroup<{[key: string]: TControl; }>`

and [this blog post](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2022/04/21/strictly-typed-forms-angular/):

> ```
> languages: new FormRecord({
>   english: new FormControl(true, { nonNullable: true }),
>   french: new FormControl(false, { nonNullable: true })
> });
> ```

---

The values of the object you pass to `new FormRecord` should be `FormControl` objects, not strings.

Comment: I've added an issue to @angular/forms git https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46298 and as I can see someone just resolved that bug. Good job

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake, I believe. The documentation says '[generic argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)' which means the one you should specify in pointy brackets `<>`, typescript syntax. Simply put a type in there, similarly to how you provide a type you're expecting from an Observable, like this:

`public emailAddresses: FormRecord<FormControl<string>>;`

Note that specifying a type like that is not mandatory and in some cases even might be redundant.

And as for creating a new instance of a record — since `FormRecord` extends well known `FormGroup`, its constructor accepts the same arguments: required `controls` and optional `validatorOrOpts` and `asyncValidator`.